# Typescript: unable to access public variable in a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to access `myVariable` inside `init()` but the variable is `undefined`, but I am able to access the variable inside `convert()`. Any suggestions what I am missing here?

```
export const MyComponent: ng.IComponentOptions = {
    templateUrl: 'MyView.html',
    bindings: {
        myVariable: '<',
    },
    controller: common.createController(MyController)
};

export class MyController {

    public myVariable: MyVariable;

    constructor($scope) {
        this.scope = $scope;
        this.init().then(() => {
            this.convert();
        });

        private init(): Promise<void> {
        console.log("init(): ", this.myVariable); //Error --> undefined
        //Call REST API and return a promise            
    }

    private convert(): void {
        console.log("convert(): ", this.myVariable); //No Error
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `MyController.myVariable`? When you are not setting it, it will remain undefined (or fail to compile in TS 2.8 with option strict).

Comment: Your problem most likely is that you set the variable after the constructor and before the promise is resolved. So it is important to know where the value is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this happens because `init()` is being called before the base constructor - the base constructor is usually what sets the variable in view libraies.

I don't know what view library you're using but it looks like angular. In this case, angular will set the binding after your constructor runs (it needs to create the class before it can assign the binding, and since it doesn't provide a base class it can't utilize that for binding in the constructor)

The Angular API exposes life-cycle methods similar to react, you need the `$onInit` hook which will be called after the constructor and binding has finished.

You can read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: There is no base constructor here and TS requires the `super` call in a derived class, so the whole code would not run if this would be the problem.

Comment: Adding super() throws error: 'super' can only be referenced in a derived class. MyController is a base class.

Comment: @david i understand, please review my revised answer